# Testing Thread.sleep with PowerMock not working

Tags: java, mockito, powermockito

To simplify things, I'm trying to verify that Thread.sleep() is called in the method below using PowerMock.

```java
public class Sleeper {
  public void sleep() throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(10);
  }
}
```

Test class

```java
public class SleeperTest {

  // Mock setup done here to mock Sleeper instance

  @Test
  public void testSleep throws Exception {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Thread.class);
    sleeper.sleep();
    PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
    Thread.sleep(Mockito.anyLong());
  }

}
```

I feel that this is all I'm supposed to do to get it to work but I get the following error when I try to run it.

```
Wanted but not invoked java.lang.Thread.sleep(0);
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

Versions

```
 testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-module-junit4', version: '1.6.2'
 testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-mockito', version: '1.6.6'
```

Interestingly though if Thread.sleep is called within the test method the test passes.

```java
// This works
@Test
public void testSleep() throws Exception
{
  PowerMockito.mockStatic(Thread.class);
  Thread.sleep(Mockito.anyLong());
  PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
  Thread.sleep(Mockito.anyLong());
}
```

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why? Don't tst the platform. Test *behaviour.* Time it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you annotate your test class for running static mocking with PowerMock? You should annotate it this way:

```
@PrepareForTest(Sleeper.class)
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class SleeperTest {

  // Mock setup done here to mock Sleeper instance

  @Test
  public void testSleep throws Exception {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Thread.class);
    sleeper.sleep();
    PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
    Thread.sleep(Mockito.anyLong());
  }

}
```

Please give it a try with this setup... I have tried replicating your code but got a lot of trouble with PowerMock's compatibility and versioning, and gave up. As a matter of fact, you should avoid writing static methods that would need to be mocked for testing. You should write it so that it does not depend on the state of your program.